# How to display using ng-bind and ng-repeat using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs

I need to use ng-repeat with ng-bind to display data into a table but what I have tried doesn't display any data,where am I going wrong with the code that I tried?
HTML:

```
<tbody id="ngDowntimeBody">
<tr ng-repeat="previousdowntime in GetPreviousDowntimeEvents.PreviousDowntimeEvents">
     <td ng-bind="previousdowntime.CategoryId"></td>
      <td ng-bind="previousdowntime.StartTime"></td>
      <td ng-bind="previousdowntime.EndTime"></td>
      <td ng-bind="previousdowntime.Comment"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
function GetPreviousDowntimeEvents($http) {
     var self = this;

     self.PreviousDowntimeEvents = [];
     self.AjaxData = ngHesto.Ajax.Get($http
        , {
          url: PREVIOUS_DOWNTIME_EVENTS
          , success: function (data) {
           self.PreviousDowntimeEvents = data.data[0];
           console.log(self.PreviousDowntimeEvents);
            }
       });
 }

var ngAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
ngAppModule.controller('DowntimeController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.GetPreviousDowntimeEvents = new GetPreviousDowntimeEvents($http);  
}]);
```

The Data doesn't get displayed

This is the response I get back:

```
{EventId: "10", DepartmentId: "7", CategoryId: "10", StartTime: "2014-08-19T10:00:00", EndTime: "2014-08-19T10:10:00",Comment:"Test"}
```

Comment: Can you also post a sample response? The one which is being assigned in this line- self.PreviousDowntimeEvents = data.data[0];

Comment: Because when I run this code with some sample data, it's executed without any issues. This is what I assigned to test on my side- self.PreviousDowntimeEvents = [{'CategoryId' : 1, 'StartTime' : 'Today 1', 'EndTime' : 'Tomorrow 1', 'Comment' : 'Some comments 1'},
                                    {'CategoryId' : 2, 'StartTime' : 'Today 2', 'EndTime' : 'Tomorrow 2', 'Comment' : 'Some comments 2'},
                                    {'CategoryId' : 3, 'StartTime' : 'Today 3', 'EndTime' : 'Tomorrow 3', 'Comment' : 'Some comments 3'}];

Comment: I only need to display the response into the table

Comment: Works for me. Try http://jsfiddle.net/orj8wdps/1/ - looks to me you are in fact not assigning an array to `self.PreviousDowntimeEvents` but a single object. Try `self.PreviousDowntimeEvents = data.data` instead of `self.PreviousDowntimeEvents = data.data[0]`.

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv thanks a lot I didn't realize that I had to remove the [0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS

```
function GetPreviousDowntimeEvents($http) {
     var self = this;

     self.PreviousDowntimeEvents = [];
     self.AjaxData = ngHesto.Ajax.Get($http
        , {
          url: PREVIOUS_DOWNTIME_EVENTS
          , success: function (data) {
           self.PreviousDowntimeEvents = data.data;
           console.log(self.PreviousDowntimeEvents);
            }
       });
 }

var ngAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
ngAppModule.controller('DowntimeController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.GetPreviousDowntimeEvents = new GetPreviousDowntimeEvents($http);  
}]);
```

HTML

```
  <tbody id="ngDowntimeBody">
                       <tr ng-repeat="previousdowntime in GetPreviousDowntimeEvents.PreviousDowntimeEvents">
                       <td>{{previousdowntime.CategoryId}}</td>
                       <td>{{previousdowntime.StartTime}}</td>
                       <td>{{previousdowntime.EndTime}}</td>
                       <td>{{previousdowntime.Comment}}</td>
                   </tr>
              </tbody> 
         </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you do not need this new staff there

instead of

```
ngAppModule.controller('DowntimeController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.GetPreviousDowntimeEvents = new GetPreviousDowntimeEvents($http);  
}]);
```

use either

```
ngAppModule.controller('DowntimeController', ['$scope','$http', GetPreviousDowntimeEvents]);
```

or return something in your GetPreviousDowntimeEvents function

```
function GetPreviousDowntimeEvents($http) {
 //...
  return self;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct and does not address his real issue. `GetPreviousDowntimeEvents` is a "class" that he instantiates by calling `new GetPreviousDowntimeEvents(...)` and putting that instance on the `$scope`.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: It is a class - correct, but I think it is not necessary, at least for the snippet.

Comment: There's no `self.PreviousDowntimeEvents` if you don't call it.